# list of random numbers to list of consecutive real numbers in python

Tags: python

I have the following two-column database in a CSV file:

```
31 ID1
42 ID2
22 ID3
42 ID4
```

Which contains class number in the first column and the information in the second (separated by a space).

I would like it to be transformed to ordered as real numbers. The first element will be assigned a class number of 1, and so on. But the class numbers have to be the same order as in the original file, as in the following example:

```
1 ID1
2 ID2
3 ID3
2 ID4
```

I think this can be done with the `zip` functions. Does anyone has any recommendations for this?

Comment: `[[data[i], i] for i in range(len(data))]`

Comment: @user2255757 or simply `zip(data, range(len(data)))`

Comment: @user2255757 or even `[[v, i]  for i, v in enumerate(data)]`

Comment: or, `map(list, map(reversed, enumerate(data)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a `defaultdict` and a counter to count up class labels

```
import csv
import itertools
import collections

ID = itertools.count(1)
labels = collections.defaultdict(lambda : next(ID))
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=' ', dialect='excel')
    for val, name in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' '):
        outfile.writerow([name.strip(), labels[val]])
```

**EDIT** (some documentation):

`itertools.count(1)` gives you a stream of numbers: 1,2,3,4.... These will serve as your class labels

`collections.defaultdict` works like a dictionary, but takes an optional argument. When you ask a defaultdict for the value of a key that it doesn't have, it creates that key, adds it to the dictionary, and gives it a default value specified by the optional argument. I gave it a default value that asks for the next value of that `itertools.count` object that I created. So, if you put a new value in the defaultdict, it gets a fresh class label

So for each line in the input file, I get the class label by asking the defaultdict for it. If the value (say 42) has been seen before, it gives me the previously assigned class label. But if the value hasn't been seen before, it creates a new class label (because of how defaultdict and itertools.count work) for the value, and gives me that new class label

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `list` to store classes without repetition and then use the `element's index + 1` as the new "class id", for example:

```
# First, import data -- you may use the `csv` module also
filename = 'test.csv'
encoding = 'utf-8'
with open(filename) as fobj:
    data = fobj.read().decode(encoding)
data = [line.split() for line in lines.split('\n')]

# Create the classes list -- can't use a `set` because we need it ordered
classes = []
for x, y in data:
    if y not in classes:
        classes.append(y)

# To see the final result:
for x, y in data:
    print x, classes.index(y) + 1
```